Registry Value RDVDenyWriteAccess changed by DeviceEnroller.exe
The registry value for RDVDenyWriteAccess and FDVDenyWriteAccess are both being changed randomly from 0 to 1 which then prevents me from adding or deleting files from my fixed or removable drives. A manual registry edit to change the values back again and a reboot is all that is required, but this is a complete pain.
Using Process monitor, I can see that it is being changed by DeviceEnroller.exe although is being queried (not changed) by omadmclient.exe(which has BitlockerCsp.dll in its stack) from time to time as well. DeviceEnroller.exe is actually deleting the value first and then setting it again immediately afterwards. Actually, it is deleting the value 3 times every time, the first one succeeds and the following 2 fail. It then sets the value twice - both succeed.
This does not happen at a set time either. Yesterday at 07:03 and 21:43 then today at 06:33 and 21:44. I wasn't using the computer at any of those times.
It has taken me months to get this far, but I am no closer to figuring out how to resolve this issue.
Any help will be gratefully appreciated.

Solved it. I noticed in the stack Enterprise Policy Manager was listed. It turns out that Intune was still applying some group policies from a little while ago when I used to do some consultancy work for an IT Company.
I simply removed them from "Access Work or School" in settings and no longer have the issue.
